# relative import error in python trying to import version

Tags: python

I run my python project both locally in my development environment and from an installed package.

in my main.py I want to get the version from **init**.py:

```
from . import version
```

but I get the error:

```
ValueError: attempted relative import in non-package
```

my directory structure is as follows:

```
./proj1/main.py
./proj1/__init__.py
```

I'm running it via

```
 cd proj1 && ./main.py
```

I use the version for setup.py and within my main.py to output the version.

Comment: Only when importing `proj1` does it become a package. By running `main.py` as a *top-level script* you removed that attribute; `proj1` is just another directory now, not a package.